# What is 'column' in an apex class error message?

Tags: apex

I got  error like this many time while running  test classes:

> External entry point Class.SoapApi28Adapter_Test.myUnitTest: **line
>   281, column 1**

I don't know what meant by column 1, I know that there is an error at line 281.

Comment: Sometimes salesforce tries to display not only line or error, but position of error as well (number of character in line). That doesn't always work.
btw, that error is much better than External entry point -1, -1. At least you know the line

Answer (score 3):

abcde fdh
123456789

digits are the columns

> The digit below each letter represents the letter's column position
>   along at the line number indicated.

Comment: @Ratan, yes it does answer the question. "digits are the columns" means `The digit below each letter represents the letter's column position along at the line number indicated`. It just wasn't phrased as clearly as I hopefully just did.